# Oracle Apex Function in IG Query slowing down application

Tags: sql, performance, oracle-apex

I have an apex interactive grid that uses the following query:

```
select emp_id, get_emp_count(emp_id),emp_grade,emp_org,emp_unit from employees;
```

The query used function get_emp_count is something like this:

```
select count(*) from (select emp_id,emp_grade,emp_sal,emp_dept,emp_unit from employees a where (nvl(emp_id,0),nvl(emp_grade,'~'),nvl(emp_sal,0),nvl(emp_dept,'~'),nvl(emp_unit,'~')) not in 
select nvl(emp_id,0),nvl(emp_grade,'~'),nvl(emp_sal,0),nvl(emp_dept,'~'),nvl(emp_unit,'~') from employees_backup  b
where a.emp_id=b.emp_id);
```

This query is slowing down the application page.

Need suggestions as to how can it be tuned or what's the alternative to nvl?

)

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does `employees_backup` table contain per each `emp_id`? Query you posted suggests that there can be "0 - n" rows, as you're comparing all (?) columns. If there can be up to one row, perhaps you should check only whether `emp_id` exists in that table.

An alternative might be this; I don't know whether it would behave better, same or worse than your current function, but - you can try it and see what happens.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_count (par_emp_id IN employees.emp_id%TYPE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   retval  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO retval
     FROM (
             SELECT emp_id,
                    emp_grade,
                    emp_sal,
                    emp_dept,
                    emp_unit
               FROM employees
              WHERE emp_id = par_emp_id
             MINUS
             SELECT emp_id,
                    emp_grade,
                    emp_sal,
                    emp_dept,
                    emp_unit
               FROM employees_backup
              WHERE emp_id = par_emp_id
          );

   RETURN retval;
END;
```

Comment: The number of rows curently is 500 but it will increase upto 100000